# PHP Variable Reading Differently When Typed

Tags: php, variables

I am having a very unusual problem. When I use this script to post to Blogger it works perfectly when I actually type the blog ID in for example

```
$blogID = '2542513707206115453';
```

But when I have the script scrape the Blog ID automatically it gives me errors talking about an invalid `uri` even though the script is scraping the exact same number as I am typing.

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

$blog = file_get_contents($link.'/feeds/posts/default');
preg_match('/tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-(.*?)-/', $blog, $blogID);
$blogID = rtrim($blogID[1], date("Y"));


$service = 'blogger';
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service, null,
    Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::DEFAULT_SOURCE, null, null,
    Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::CLIENTLOGIN_URI, 'GOOGLE');

$gdClient = new Zend_Gdata($client);


$entry = $gdClient->newEntry();
$entry->title = $gdClient->newTitle($title);
$entry->content = $gdClient->newContent($body);
$entry->content->setType('text');  
$uri = 'http://www.blogger.com/feeds/'.$blogID.'/posts/default';
$createdPost = $gdClient->insertEntry($entry, $uri);
$idText = split('-', $createdPost->id->text);
$newPostID = $idText[2];
```

I have no idea how this could even happen since the `$blogID` is the exact same number whether scraped or whether typed. And yes I have double and triple checked that when scraped it is the exact same number. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using regex to parse XML?

Answer (score 2):

What is the point of this call?

```
$blogID = rtrim($blogID[1], date("Y"));
```

The 2nd option in rtrim specifies which characters should be trimmed from the end of the string. Since you're using a date (`2013` at present), you're trying to eliminate ANY `2`, `0`, `1` and `3` chars from the string.

That means, given your

```
$blogID = '2542513707206115453';
```

you'll actually end up with

```
$blogID = '254251370720611545';
                             ^--- see? no 3
```

which is **NOT** the same number

Comment: I'm wondering if the OP is getting the string `<num>2013` back, and wants to remove the `2013` from it. Might be worthwhile to note that if that's the case, just do a `substr( $blogID[1], 0, -4);`.

Comment: The script above is scraping this number 2542513707206115453 even if I change the script to  $blogID = str_replace("2013", "", $blogID[1]); it still doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried   'substr( $blogID[1], 0, -4);' with no luck either. The script will only work if I type it manually.

Comment: @dan: do some debugging. echo out $uri right before you use it, and make sure it's identical to what you expect it to be. copy/paste it into a browser, test it, etc... just because you're scraping the number properly doesn't mean you aren't mangling it before you use it in the ->insertEntry() call.